# Why there is no string in my C mpi program?

Tags: c, string, char, mpi, strlen

I want to send message(greeting) from 0 process to 1-6 process, and add the number i behind the message every time(G_str), but the result shows that

```
processor 1 received string:  from processor 0 
processor 2 received string:  from processor 0 
...
```

I don't know it didn't show the message I want to send

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int PID, P;
    char greeting [] = "hello";
    char replying [] ="nice to see you";
    char G_str [10];
    char R_str [10];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &P);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &PID);

    int len_g = strlen(greeting);
    int len_r = strlen(replying);
    int len_G = strlen(G_str); 
    //send and receive//

    if (PID == 0){

        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {   
            sprintf(G_str, "%s%d", greeting,i);              
            MPI_Send(&G_str, len_G, MPI_CHAR, i, 77, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    else{    
        MPI_Recv(&G_str, len_G, MPI_CHAR, 0, 77, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("processor %d received string %s from processor 0 \n", PID, G_str);      
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

I guess the problem is on the length of G_str, but how to correct it?

Comment: `int len_G = strlen(G_str);` is equal to `0` because `G_str` wasn't initialized

Comment: @Cid actually in this case `strlen(G_str)` is UBS, it could return any value, it could even crash the program or do other nasty things

Comment: `char G_str [10];` is not initialized. `char G_str [10];` -> `char G_str [10] = "";`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have change char G_str [10];  to char G_str [10] = ""; but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char G_str [10];
```

`G_str` is not initialized. You simply declare the `char` array `G_str` with that statement, but do not initialize a string.

Therefore with doing:

```
int len_G = strlen(G_str);
```

you will get [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), since `strlen` searches for a `\0` character of a NUL-terminated string, which obviously isn´t existant in `G_str`.

---

Change:

```
char G_str [10];
```

to at least:

```
char G_str [10] = "";
```

or instead:

```
char G_str[10];
G_str[0] = 0;
```

to initialize an empty string.

If you want to have the length of the array of `G_str` in `len_G` you should not use `strlen` since it only counts characters until it finds the terminating `\0` character of a string, leaving the `\0` and the rest of the array (if further `char` elements after the `\0` remain) off the count. Instead you should use the `sizeof` operator:

```
int len_G = sizeof(G_str);
```

to get the capacity of the entired array `G_str`.

Comment: I have change char G_str [10]; to char G_str [10] = ""; but it didn't work

Comment: @KongL37 Try it with: `int len_G = sizeof(G_str);`